# Exhibiting weird behavior from Xfce after installing samba

Tags: 64-bit, xfce

After installing samba, I rebooted and now the top bar from every window I missing (where you can minimize, expand, or close, and drag window around).  What gives?  Another thing I notice that I while in command prompt, I was not able to see anything in the media folder until I browsed there through File Manager, then the associated media (antoher sata hd).  Then I would appear in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted the `.cache` file and all works a-ok.

Logged out of my sessions, did `ctrl+alt+F1`, the performed the following...

```
sudo rm -R .cache
sudo restart lightdm
```

Imediately brought me back to my Xfce session showing everything correctly!